Is it possible to construct nuclear power plant with element $\rm Be$?
Perhaps the most fundamental reaction in nuclear power generation is the one in which neutrons collide with 235 uranium, and I wonder if 235 uranium can be converted into 9 beryllium.
9 beryllium produces neutrons by (n,2n) reaction when high-energy electrons are incident.
Experimental data showing that the micro cross-section of the (n,2n) reaction is 0.7 barn at 3.25 Mev can be obtained by searching.
I'd like to know if 9 beryllium can be used, even though it's more inefficient than 235 uranium or 239 plutonium.
It doesn't matter if the multiplication factor k is too small, even if the value of the multiplication factor k cannot exceed 1.
The fission micro cross-section value of 235 uranium at 0.0253 ev exceeds 500.
Certainly 0.7 is a very small number than 500, but I would like to know if I can predict the k value if possible.

Note that beryllium is used in reactors, especially outside of neutron moderators, as a neutron reflector.

What is the Q value of the (n,2n) reaction? How does that energy of the reaction compare with the required 3.25MeV neutrons to initiate it?

" It doesn't matter if the multiplication factor k is too small, even if the value of the multiplication factor k cannot exceed 1 " ...
On the contrary, it is of the FIRST IMPORTANCE !!!!
You need to get critical mass and a chain reaction if you want to produce a NOTABLE source of energy.
Only so-called “fissile” materials have this neutron property.
There are many known reactions (n, 2n), (n , 3n), ..., (n, 5n), even if some are exothermic (which remains to be verified), none will ever give the development of a chain reaction.
As assumed, the nuclear reaction 9Be(n,2n) that produces 2 alpha particles and 2 neutrons is an endothermic reaction, whose QM balance is negative and is about -1.6 Mev.
Which means that it takes more energy to produce it than you can recover. It is not the number of neutrons produced that matters, it is the energy balance of the nuclear reaction.

I'm sorry I didn't reveal everything in the question. I'm not interested in extracting energy from beryllium, but merely in whether a chain reaction occurs even slightly. If achieving k = 1 is impossible, then additional high-energy neutrons can be introduced. What I want to know is if the chain reaction can happen even a little bit and as a result, reduce the high energy neutrons that need to be incident.

@SungJinPark You can't have a "little bit" of a chain reaction. Either the reaction rate is increasing exponentially - which is a chain reaction - or it isn't, and there is no chain reaction. It's a binary either-or situation. Nuclear reactors work by having controls that alternately start and stop a chain reaction to achieve the desired power output.
